# What is the best way to keep track of the commit logs after a branch reintegration in SVN?

Tags: svn, version-control, project-management, cornerstone

I'm have some to little experience in SVN. We're using Cornerstone as our SVN client in our iOS Xcode development.

As per norm, for every project, we have branches/tags/trunk. We have decided to have our trunk branch to have latest released stable code (normally the App Store version).

We also have decided to have a branch called "main" which will be the Adhoc released code. "development" branch to merge the changes from all developers and each branch for every developers.

After a feature has been implemented or bug has been fixed, a developer will merge his branch into the development branch. From development branch, the main branch will be merged. And so on for trunk.

Unfortunately, all the commit logs that has been done in developer branch will be lost after we do the branch "Reintegration" (in order to have a clean copy of merged changes from all developers)

So what would be the best practice for us to keep track the commit logs while at the same time be able to re-branch to get merged changes from all other developers?

If there's a way to do it from Cornerstone, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After you reintegrate and commit, [block that commit](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.reintegratetwice) from being merged back into your branch. That way you can keep the branch alive, and you don't need to overwrite its history.